# Why would we multiply something by 10 if it's zero

Tags: c

***I don't understand why we multiply i by 10 if it's already a zero.
so i would appreciate if some could explain why did we use this type of expressions to solve this problem.***

```
#include <stdio.h>


main(void)
{
    int n, num = 0;
    printf("Enter any number to print individuellement : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n != 0) // Instructions à répéter
    {


> ***num = (num * 10) + (n % 10);*** 

        `n = n / 10;`
    }
    while(num != 0)    // Instructions à répéter
    {
        switch(num % 10)
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

.
.
.

        num = num / 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not always zero. After the first iteration, it's the result of the previous addition.

Comment: i know sir, it's just that there is this expression " (num * 10) " which i really don't understand if the previous value of 'num' is Zero, then why would we multiply 10 by 0

Comment: It won't be 0 the next time.

Comment: i haven't understood yet, because we haven't putten any expression or function to change the 'num' value, then how could it change by it self.

Comment: `num = (num * 10) + (n % 10);` changes the value.

Comment: If `n` is `13`, this will change `num` to `3`.

Comment: sir please one more example with 4 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

num is initialised to be zero only in the beginning.
After each iteration, its value changes as per the condition defined.
As a simplified example, you can see in the for loop, a variable is initialised to zero and then condition is provided and instructed to increment or decrement (usually) until the condition satisfies.
Initialising a variable to zero is to assign the value 0 to it if not, it will take the value of memory block.

Comment: That's a great explanation Mr, thanks for your time.

Comment: Great to hear that. Please consider upvoting the answer if that helped.

Answer (score 1):

`num` is only zero the first time through the loop.

Suppose you enter `6521`. The first time through the loop, it does

```
num = (0 * 10) + (6521 % 10);
```

which sets `num = 1`. Then it divides `n` by 10. So the next time through the loop it does:

```
num = (1 * 10) + (652 % 10);
```

which sets `num = 12`. The next iteration does:

```
num = (12 * 10) + (65 % 10);
```

which sets `num = 125`. The next iteration does:

```
num = (125 * 10) + (6 % 10);
```

which sets `num = 1256`.

Then the loop ends because dividing `n` by `10` results in `0`.

The result of this is to reverse the digits of the number that was entered.

Comment: Thanks you Sir, now i got the whole idea of how it works